Debian 12 + Cinnamon - Weird issue with UI displaying, GTK, it doesn't render unless hovered over
I have been a long-time linux user in general, about 8 years now so I am not a complete noob, usually when something like this happens I can just reinstall the DE but I really want to actually fix this issue and not dance around it.
I have recorded a video showing what is happening to me so that it's easy to understand, it seems to affect ALL GTK applications ( even nemo ).
Link to my recording
I would appreciate any kind of help with this, it's not the first time it happens to me on GTK based DEs ( Gnome, Cinnamon, etc... )
